# I have a text file of the following format and need to convert it into a 2D matrix in python

Tags: python

I need to store all the numbers without the alphabets in my matrix. Also, the fact that there is unequal spacing between the numbers is making it really hard to convert to a matrix. This is a pssm matrix if that helps in anyway and I need to compute the shannon entropy from this matrix. 
The matrix is spaced to look correct but this is making it really hard for me to write correct code to store it as a 2D matrix. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
       A  R  N  D  C  Q  E  G  H  I  L  K  M  F  P  S  T  W  Y  V
1 T   -3 -4 -3 -4 -4 -3 -4 -4 -5 -3 -4 -3 -3 -5 -4 -1  8 -5 -4 -3
2 I   -4 -5 -6 -6 -4 -5 -6 -6 -6  7  0 -5  0 -2 -5 -5 -3 -5 -4  2
3 G   -1 -4 -2 -3 -4 -4 -4  7 -4 -6 -6 -3 -5 -5 -4  2 -2 -5 -5 -5
4 M   -3 -4 -5 -6 -4 -2 -5 -6 -4  2  1 -4 10 -3 -5 -4 -2 -4 -4  0
5 V    0 -4 -5 -5 -3 -4 -4 -5 -5  5  2 -4  0 -2 -4 -3 -2 -4 -3  4
6 V    4 -4 -4 -4  3 -3 -3 -2 -4  0 -2 -3 -2 -3 -3 -1 -1 -5 -3  4
7 I   -3 -4 -5 -5 -3 -4 -5 -6 -5  6  3 -4  2 -1 -5 -4 -3 -4 -3  2
8 H   -3 -4  0  7 -6 -2 -1  1  5 -6 -6 -3 -5 -5 -4 -2 -3 -6 -4 -5
9 K    2  0 -1 -1 -3  1  1 -1 -1 -3 -2  3 -2 -3 -1  1  0 -3 -2 -1
```

and so on for 141 rows.

Comment: If you have any code you've written to try to solve this problem yourself, please provide it along with a description of what it's doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, spacing can actually be predicted - but I'll assume it can't be as you mentioned.

Sounds like you can use the help of regular expressions. Using `\s+` implies "One space or more", which should suit your needs. Make sure to get rid of the beginnings of the lines before or during the regex manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by new lines, then by spaces:

```
linesplit = matrix.split("\n")
grid = list()
for line in linesplit:
    grid.append(line.split(" "))
```

Then, if you don't want the lettering along the top and side:

```
del grid[0]
for line in grid:
    del line[0]
```

This is assuming that your matrix has one space between each number. If it doesn't, first run this on the string:

```
import re
matrix = re.sub("\s+", str(), matrix)
```